# Idea java maven project reference

Tags: intellij-idea

I have two spring boot projects. project-model, project-api. project-api is dependency on project-model. In eclipse(STS), I can right click project-api-> project reference->select project-model as a reference project. Anything change in project-model, project-api will be notice the changes.
How can I config the same in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency.

Comment: @CrazyCoder if you command+click the reference class, it Opens as readonly. and also you have to pre-build the model project.

Comment: Do you use Gradle or Maven?

Comment: @CrazyCoder maven project

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module. You need a parent pom and import from it.

Comment: It seems that I have to work on them as two projects.  Project-model is also reference by other project(other team). They are one different git repositories. Multi-Module Project will give some new management problems. There is no perfect solution。 Thank you @ CrazyCoder

Comment: It should be no problem using 2 git repositories for different modules in IntelliJ IDEA. You can have your own module for the root pom.xml that will not affect the other 2 modules in any way.